# Is selling ciggarette lighters permissible?

Tags: halal-haram

I got a job offer from a company that manufactures ciggarette lighters, oven lighters, disposable razors and stationary. Its a very attractive package almost 30% higher than what im getting now. I have a current job with absolutely no doubts on the products that I sell. Would it be wrong to work for such an organisation who is into lighters?

Comment: What would your job role be?

Comment: My job would be to revamp Sales and distribution @ Aboudi

Comment: What items will you be selling?

Answer (score 1):

There is no harm in working with a lighter manufacturer. While lighters can be used for cigarettes, they are also used for general household appliances, such as candles, certain stoves, etc. A lighter is just that, a tool.

It would be an eye-brow raiser if the manufacturer is not a general maker, but a specialized one that specifically targets smokers. For example a Marlboro/Philip Morris lighter manufacturer (if that even exists), then that would necessitate a discussion and a verdict. But apart from that, it's like working in a knife manufacturer - the customer can cut veggies or throats. That has nothing to do with you.

And Allah knows best.

Answer (score 0):

**Fistly** let me give you some general rule in  the **Figih rule** say "الاصل في العادات الاباحة"  means all that is not mentioned is permissible that the light the car everything can be used permissible that mean any thing as general not determined it Haraam or Halal its Halal  **But** when it helped to reach the Haram is haraam or helped in the act of haraam  because the **Figih rule** "الوسائل لها احكام المقاصد" means if you use something for purpose it has its shar'i ruling.

The cigarettes is forbidden in the shar'i rule because its destroy your body in the Quran Allah says :"و لاتقتلوا أنفسكم إن الله كان بكم رحيماً" 
and prophet Mohamed said:"لا ضرر و لا ضرار " means not to harm your body or others
you can enter this blog to get more information about cigarettes https://islamqa.info/en/10922